# why does mesh go crazy when I activate a collection?

Tags: mesh, retopology

I have a sculpted head in blender and I'm retopoligizing it. For that process, I have a

- mirror modifier
- subdivision surface modifier
- shrinkwrap modifier

Since I don't want to have to high poly of a mesh for now, I don't apply them. Here's how it looks:
[image: screenshot of my setup]
then, I activate (or deactivate and reactivate, it doesn't matter) one of my collections and my mesh goes crazy like this:
[image: screenshot of my mesh going crazy]
[image: clearer look at my messed up mesh]

the only way to get the mesh back to it's original form is to undo until I rename the step that I rename the mesh. Also, taking of the modifiers doesn't work. I'd like to know if this is my fault pls.

Edit, applying the modifiers solved the problem, but I would still like to know how to fix it if I don't want to appply them. Thanks!

Comment: It seems strange that your objects would have drivers. What exactly are the drivers controlling?

Comment: it doesn't have drivers, only modifiers

Comment: The arrow icon in the outliner indicates that an object has driven properties.

Comment: well, that's weird, I never set a driver for that. How do I take it off?

Comment: Shrinkwrap modifier usually looks like this. Maybe something messed up there. How did you use it to sculpting?

Comment: I used it for remeshing on top of face snaping. Also,the modifiers in the post are in order. But I don't think it was the shrinkwrap, since it didn't come back to normal when I took it off.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug?